# HTML5 <video> tag not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video

The following code displays a video control. The user can successfully watch the video in Safari, Firefox, Chrome, both via desktop and mobile browsers.

The video control does NOT work in the latest version of Internet Explorer (11?) -- neither desktop nor mobile.

Here's the code in question:

```
 <div id="videoDiv" class="wrappableBlock">
     <h2><img src="/code/images/video.png"/>Introductory Video</h2>
     <video controls preload="metadata" >
       <source src="/code/images/video.mp4#t=8" type="video/mp4" >
       <source src="/code/images/video.ogg#t=8" type="video/ogg" >
       <em>Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</em>
     </video>
 </div>
```

According to the documentation referenced [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats), Internet Explorer should be able to process MP4 video files provided that they are H.264 / AAC encoded. My video meets these specifications.

The symptoms are:

(1) In desktop version of Internet Explorer (11.0) the video player shows up but pressing the play button does nothing.

(2) In the mobile version (latest version as of 5/12/14 @ Microsoft store) the video player shows as an inoperable black square. The dimensions of the square are correct but there's no way to interact with it.

In no case does my default code `<em>Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</em>` display.

What else shall I try? It's not necessary to find a working solution for IE versions prior to 10.

**UPDATE**: Another tidbit.. Entering the full path to the video file(s) in the IE URL area executes a download of the file. So it's not a "file not found" situation. It's accessible.

Also... The Internet Explorer network tab shows that IE isn't even bothering to query for the file. As opposed to the other browsers which automatically execute a GET request for the video.

Comment: What does the console say? Is your server set up with correct mime-types for mp4? (check console)

Comment: Yes, the mime types are set up correctly. I know that's the case because I can see the mime types being returned when I look at the HTTP request/response stream in the Firebug log. The server is IIS running on Windows 2008 BTW. When you suggest looking at the console, is this something that's in Internet Explorer? Will be happy to check it out.

Comment: Sure, just hit F12 and IE11 should pop up a console.

Comment: Aha, yes, I see. Ok, the only error it returned was one telling me that I should've included `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of my document. I added it but it didn't make a difference. What's interesting is that on the network tab, I can see that it's not even trying to load the video file(s), neither the .mp4 or the .ogg. So it's not like the file is bad. It's not even trying to load it. Weird! This is in contrast to Firefox, etc. which actually attempts to retrieve the video file via a GET request.

Comment: Without seeing the full html/file structure it's gonna be a guess: try to specify the url *without* the prefixed forwards slash, ie. `src="code/images/video.mp4"` (and without the #-part). And when you tried the url directly in the address bar, did it play properly (assuming yes, but you don't state - and QT is not installed?) ?

Comment: No, when requesting the video in the address bar, IE asks where I'd like to download the file. It doesn't attempt to play it. Even if Windows 2008 lacked the proper plugin to play the MP4 file, you'd think the Windows mobile device would be able to play it. Removing the leading forward slash didn't make a difference. IE still doesn't even execute a GET request, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having exactly the same problem with IE 11. Most other similar issues are to do with codecs, but this is the first I've come across someone else with the problem that a request for the video file isn't even made to the server.

Comment: I believe I am having the [exact same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079053/media-resource-not-showing-up-in-network-tab). Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

first check your ie version. if it is lower than 9. Then you need to use flash player. or you can also used embeded option in Internet exploer 8 or less than 8.

like this 
{

```
<video id="Video1" controls width="100%" height="auto" poster="pic.png" >
<source src="video.mp4" type='video/mp4;' />
<embed src="video.mp4" wmode="opaque">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
</embed>
</video>
```

} It works in me..

Answer (score 0):

Verify that video playback isn't [disabled in your Internet zones](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2014/12/31/unable-to-play-html5-videos-in-ie.aspx) from a group policy setting.